# Sending emails with Perl through SSL

Tags: perl, email, ssl

I'm trying to send an email with Perl through SSL. The best package I've come across, based on examples, is Net::SMTP::SSL. This appears to be the standard. Unfortunately, the constructor always returns `undef` for me:

```
my $smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new('smtp.server.com', Port => 25, Debug => 1);
```

I have verified, re-verified, and re-re-verified the server name and port number using a .NET application that does essentially the same thing. Everything works fine with the .NET app, so I don't see any reason why I should have problems connecting to the smtp server.

It would be extremely helpful if the module would provide some sort of debugging information, but `$!` is coming up blank. Is there any explanation for why the `$smtp` variable would be come up undefined? Or is there any way I can find some useful debugging information from the constructor call?

Edit: Yes, I know that port 25 is a weird port to use with SSL. I don't know why this port was chosen, but this is the port that's being used. Unfortunately I'm constrained by time and it's going to be easier for me to figure this out with another technology than try to debug the cpan module. Thanks everyone for helping.

Comment: Take a look at the source to see what that call to `new` does.

Comment: @Ether I'm having a tough time understanding the source. As you might imagine, I'm not completely fluent in Perl. If you could elaborate in a complete answer it would be very helpful to both myself and anyone else who finds himself in a similar situation in the future.

Comment: Did you install Crypt::SSLEay or IO::Socket::SSL?

Comment: @Alessandro I installed using cpan as Ether suggested. I tried installing IO::Socket::SSL explicitly using cpan and that didn't fix the problem. I haven't installed Crypt::SSLEay.

Comment: Are you completely sure that the connection obtained by the .Net application is actually secured by SSL, and that there was not an automatic fall-back to an unsecured connection?

Comment: I find it odd that the server is expecting SSL connections on port 25. Did you try 465?

Comment: I second ikegami's comment. It is unlikely that SMTPS is running on port 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Net::SMTP::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSMTP%3a%3aSSL) uses [Net::SMTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSMTP) to do its work. In looking at the [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GBARR/libnet-1.22/Net/SMTP.p) for Net::SMTP in its `new` sub, `undef` is returned for a number of error conditions. To start, you can either step through this function call in a debugger, or manually sprinkle print statements throughout its code to see how far it is getting before bailing.

Also, check that you have [IO::Socket::SSL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aSSL) installed - this is used for the network operations. If you installed your modules using the `cpan` client you should have it, but other package managers like rpm sometimes screw up the dependency chain.

I would also double- and triple-check that you have the right port: Net::SMTP::SSL's documentation says:

> Due to the nature of Net::SMTP's `new` method, it is not overridden to make use of a default port for the SMTPS service. Perhaps future versions will be smart like that. Port 465 is usually what you want, and it's not a pain to specify that.

Comment: So the only way to debug it is by going into the source and inserting print statements? What kind of idiot designed the SMTP module? :/

Comment: I'd also like to note that `IO::Socket::SSL` may have to be upgraded. In my out-of-the-box Perl I had version 1.962, and was getting `undef` returned by new Net::SMTP::SSL. Upgrading IO::Socket::SSL to 1.998 solved the problem.